# Polymorphic Relationships are not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have 2 models, Application and Internship.

The relationships are:

**Internship.php**

```
public function applications() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Application', 'applicationable');
}
```

**Application.php**

```
public function applicationable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

This query does not work...

```
$i = Internship::find(144)
$i->applications // this does not work
```

But, this does...

```
Application::where('applicationable_id', 144)->get() // this works
```

I am confused on what I am doing wrong and any assistance on this would be helpful.

Please Note: The project is Laravel 5.6 and I have other polymorphic relationships which are working, only this one has issues.

The raw command rendered by Eloquent for `$internship->applications` is :-

```
select * from `applications` where `applications`.`applicationable_id` = ? and `applications`.`applicationable_id` is not null and `applications`.`applicationable_type` = ?
```

Comment: Is it because your looking 144 at internship instead in application?

Comment: @ChristianGallarmin sorry I did not understand .. I first fetch the internship and then try to get their applications.. and that is what I want to do as I have internships with me and need to get their applications

Comment: what did you got when you dd($i);

Comment: Internship as expected .. its the relationship that does not work

Comment: What about the `use App\Application;` and `use App\Internship;` you have it?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Is there an error? What's the result of `dd(Internship::find(144)->applications()->toSql());`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have updated the question

Comment: Does `Application::where('applicationable_id', 144)->where('applicationable_type', 'App\Internship')->get()` also work?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir .. Ohh this does not work

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I think I found the mistake..the type column has \App\Internship

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks for making me write that full query as that showed me the wrong way of writing model name in applicationable_type column

Comment: You need applicationable_type and applicationable_id columns in your applicationable pivot table. Then maybe define public function internship()

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have id number 144 in your Internship table, otherwise it's gonna throw an error for you saying: "Trying to get property 'photos' of non-object"